# In Ocean's Twelve, how did the Night Fox make the switch?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-twelve

At the end when the Night Fox is explaining that he actually stole the Golden Egg on the first night it arrived, there's a flashback montage of how he got through the [randomized lasers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr834Cs9ncs). He stole the egg, which turns out to be replica #1 that Ocean's team planted. Then a few days later, Ocean's team swipe replica #2 and are caught afterward.

The Night Fox wanted Ocean's team to think they stole the egg successfully and beat him (so he could lord it over them), so he would have put replica #2 in place of the one he stole. There was no hubbub about it being stolen, the police would have been notified if it was noticed, so the Night Fox definitely placed a replica.

Only, in his laser-dancing scene, you can see he is definitely not carrying a replica to swap the "real" one with.

So how in the world did the 2nd fake egg get there?

---

### A rough timeline of the portions dealing with the egg

**Second Thursday. Six days left:**

> Danny and Rusty meet with Le Marc who tells them to put on a show for the Night Fox, and how to beat him. A portion of Ocean's team goes and steal's the Night Fox's paintings.

**Second Friday. Five days left:**

> The other portion of Ocean's team gets on the Paris-Rome train and steals the Egg while in transit (swapping identical bags). Danny immediately goes to the Night Fox, taunts him about the paintings, and pretends to reluctantly accept the Egg challenge, knowing he already has it in his possession. Ocean's team does some recon work at the Egg museum, purely for show (because Le Marc said the Night Fox would probably be monitoring them).

**Second Saturday. Four days left:**

> A portion of Ocean's team does more recon work that night, while the Night Fox dances his way into the museum and steals the replica Egg.

**Second Sunday. Three days left:**

> The gang does their final rundown of the plan, and Nagel arrives with his holographic Egg replica.

**Second Monday. Two days left:**

> The day of the fake heist in the museum. All of Danny’s gang gets arrested before they enter the door (as planned) except for a few members. They regroup and try to come up with a new plan, calling Tess and conning her into getting on a plane to Rome.

**Second Tuesday. One day left:**

> Tess and Saul arrive in Rome to complete the lineup for the second attempt at the Egg heist. They make the switch and place a holograph egg on the pedestal, taking the replica, but the leading detective is on to them and notices, arresting them all and taking back the bag the egg is in. Linus' mom pretends to be FBI and gets them all out of custody. Rusty takes the real Egg to Le Marc, while Tess and Danny visit the Night Fox for the big reveal.

Comment: where's your suspension of disbelief? :)

Comment: Could be maybe he visited the museum earlier and planted the replica somewhere well-hidden that only he could find, knowing full well that he'd have to battle the laser grid later. Speculation, obviously, hence why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Are you sure things happened as you saying here? your question is not clear and can you edit it to express little more simplicity?

Comment: @Vishwa sure, I can add in a timeline

Comment: This is a valid, logical question but sometimes logical questions can uncover plot holes. It may just be a 'visual' plot hole. The Ocean's movies have other such holes. It happens - it's a movie :-)